# Could not load type from assembly System.Security on .NET CORE on OSX

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core

I'm having an issue with System.Security on OSX. I'm using Visual Studio for Mac and I've made an app using a dll that I do not control in order to talk to some API.
I'm getting a weird error that I have no idea how to fix.

```
Could not load type 'System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms' from assembly 'System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

The error comes from inside the DLL. I'm using dotnet core 2.0. I've tried installing System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs from nuGet and still nothing.
Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.Net Core does not support SignedCms in .Net Core 2.0:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/14197

It is currently slated for the .Net Core 2.1 release, but that could change.